# How to capture and modify read and writes on file using Dlang or cpp

Tags: c++, linux, d

Let's say that another program is to write or read a specific file. When it does that, I need to be able to take that read or write and handle the way I like (for example, program X wants to read a file located at /path/file.txt, but program Y (my program) takes that read "request" and instead  gives program X the encryption first 2KiB of another file located at /path/file2). Essentially, any time a specified file is being read or written to, my program will be called and it will handle the read or write request in Dlang or C++. I cannot create a new file system for this :( and it has to at least work with Linux (so anything specific to Linux works). Also, it is crucial that I RESPOND to the read or write and not preprocess the result, sorry this was not clear in the example.

Comment: You can make the file a named pipe, which your program opens.

Comment: Search for and read about *inotify*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I looked into it, and it doesn't let me "redirect" the read or write requests, only tells me they happened.

Comment: @Barmar, can a named pipe mimic a file of any type (so I can open it as a txt file, edit it, and the edits will be passed on to my program and be able to take those edits and do something to another file or change those edits)?

Comment: It's just a stream of bytes, and your program can be either a reader or a writer. I'm not sure you can make it a read-write file.

Comment: If you need something more powerful than this, you need a virtual filesystem, or you need to be able to intercept library function calls.

Comment: So you want to hijack or ***hook*** the `read` and `write` system calls? Possibly on a lower level in the kernel?

Comment: You might want to look at [fuse](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse) if you need to create a virtual filesystem -- it avoids having to deal with the kernel directly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Exactly!

Comment: @G.M. thanks will look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a seek-able FIFO (named pipe). It has been proposed but as far as I know it has not been implemented yet (check Linux kernel changelogs, maybe it has but I do not know about it).

As suggested, a new, tiny filesystem is your best option. Luckily it is pretty simple to write one with the FUSE project.